# Anime Movie with a Boy Who Turns Into a Big Fish

Tags: story-identification, anime

I've been trying to find out the name of an anime in which there's *a girl who allegedly lost her father after he's enchanted by a mermaid.*

**It's a movie, not a series. Its protagonist is a girl - a child with black hair.**

She eventually becomes friends with **a boy who's able to turn into a fish so big he's capable of letting her mount on him and ride.**

Unfortunately, she can't remember any names or even a part of its title, or has any idea of the decade in which it was produced and released as she's not familiarized with relating drawing styles to year/decade of production.

I've tried dozens of titles and shots but she was pretty positive none of those I pointed was the right one.

I've never seen this Anime and this is the most my friend has managed to tell me about it. But she enjoyed it so much she'd love to watch it again. As so do I now.

Comment: [There's](https://darthsanddroids.net/episodes/0033.html) [always](https://darthsanddroids.net/episodes/0208.html) a [bigger fish...](https://darthsanddroids.fandom.com/wiki/Bigger_Fish_(Droidikar_Card))